# If the cell has a number then return the cell next to it in a sorted way - Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2007, vlookup, vba

The picture attached here is my daily work sheet where blue cells show the works I have to do.

As shown, there is numbers in front of the blue ones which are the priority of the tasks.

What i want:
I want the blue cells to be displayed in a column sorted by their priority. I have tried Vlookup but failed. Is there any method to do it?

Please help[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this condition to copy whatever tasks you need to two columns wherever you like using a separate counter. This condition means if each cell and the cell next to it have Cyan backgrounds:

```
Sheet1.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255) And Sheet1.Cells(i, j+1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
```

Then you can sort them based on their priority.